# how to convert utf-8 text to unicode text

Tags: html, api, unicode, utf-8

My Server API gives a utf-8 text, I want to display it in unicode in html, should I explicitly convert this to unicode or html, meta tag with charset can convert it for me? I am unable check this as most of the browsers are able to display unicode,

The utf-8 text I have is "Ã±"
I want to display this to "ñ"

I am also curious to know if my server behaviour is correct, if not what can I ask them to modify?

Comment: How are you accessing the server API to begin with? HTML dom APIs support only Unicode strings, typically UTF-16, so yes, you would need to convert the UTF-8 before inserting it into the HTML. `Ã±` is the UTF-8 form of `ñ` being misinterpretted in Latin-1 or similar encoding.

Comment: The server API responds with Json containing "Ã±"

Comment: again, that is actually UTF-8 that is being misinterpreted as Latin. Please show your actual code so we can see if the misinterpretation is happening on the server or in your code (most likely the latter)